# Trigger in mySQL to update a columns values

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I Wrote this trigger to update a column based on the income of a customer...

```
CREATE TRIGGER `TRG_CUST_CODE` BEFORE INSERT ON `CUSTOMER_DIM`
 FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.CUST_INCOME_AM = IF(NEW.CUST_INCOME_AM >= 55000, "H",
                        IF(NEW.CUST_INCOME_AM >= 40000 and NEW.CUST_INCOME_AM < 55000, "M",
                            IF(NEW.CUST_INCOME_AM >= 15000 AND NEW.CUST_INCOME_AM < 40000, "L","P"))
                        )
```

However all values are set to P... am I missing something that I'm over looking?

Comment: Give some sample data

Comment: CUST_INCOME_AM 28000 L 56000 H should be like that anything less than 15000 should be set to P

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for your data, but I would write this trigger as:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `TRG_CUST_CODE` BEFORE INSERT ON `CUSTOMER_DIM`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.CUST_INCOME_AM = (CASE WHEN NEW.CUST_INCOME_AM >= 55000
                                   THEN 'H'
                                   WHEN NEW.CUST_INCOME_AM >= 40000 and NEW.CUST_INCOME_AM < 55000
                                   THEN 'M'
                                   WHEN NEW.CUST_INCOME_AM >= 15000 AND NEW.CUST_INCOME_AM < 40000
                                   THEN 'L'
                                   ELSE 'P'
                              END);
END;
```

Comment: I have tried that way before because that is what w3 schools recommends, however mysql says it is wrong syntax

Comment: @ZackBunch . . . Perhaps you might need to set the delimiter before defining the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit odd that you'd be replacing the value. That's not invalid, just seems a bit strange.

The expression is testing the value of the column `CUST_INCOME_AM`, and then assigning a value to that column.

Given that you report the result is being returned as 'P', that suggests the column is character datatype (e.g. CHAR or VARCHAR).

Are you sure that is the column you want to be comparing to a numeric value?

Typically, we would expect there to be a numeric (e.g. INTEGER, DECIMAL) column that we're comparing.

```
  DELIMITER $$

  DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `TRG_CUST_CODE` $$

  CREATE TRIGGER `TRG_CUST_CODE`
  BEFORE INSERT ON `CUSTOMER_DIM`
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    SET NEW.varchar_col
      = IF(NEW.numeric_col >= 55000
          ,'H'
          ,IF(NEW.numeric_col >= 40000
             ,'M'
             ,IF(NEW.numeric_col >= 15000
                ,'L'
                ,'P'
              )
           )
        );
  END$$

  DELIMITER ;
```